# Set max height of fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fixed element that is centered on the page. I would like the element to scale smaller to 80% for smaller screens. Currently `max-height` isn't working due to the element being `fixed`.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/gop4jhm9/1

```
#myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto; // need height to auto adjust depending on content
    height: auto;  // need height to auto adjust depending on content
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 80%; // isn't working
}
```

Comment: It is working — you still see it go beyond your viewport only because you have set the top position to 100px, which pushes the element down. If you lower the percentage you can see that the element is obeying the `max-height` attribute.

Comment: Terry is right. You might want to set `overflow: hidden;` or a max-height of 100% to the image.

Comment: Do you want to change the size of the container (red box in your fiddle) or the image itself? I'm guessing the latter. In this case, try `#myDiv img` as your id in the CSS

Comment: Every answer is practically identical and results in cutting the bottom of the image off, instead of scaling the image down.

Answer (score 1):

Set `body height, because max-height works only if the parent element has a height

```
body{height: 100vh}
#myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 30%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gop4jhm9/2/)

Comment: This isn't scaling the image inside the element though?

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gop4jhm9/20/)**:

```
#myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
}

#myDiv img{
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It does work, just remove your JS and put the padding back. Won't stretch the image vertically though. http://jsfiddle.net/0zq5h40s/

Comment: This has the same problem that the other answer has. It just cuts off the bottom of the image. Image max height doesn't work.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning He edited it to stretch the image instead, if that's what you want (link in answer), or this might be interesting to look at (totally different option) http://jsfiddle.net/0zq5h40s/1/

Answer (score 0):

you could try it like this:

```
#myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20%; //this sets the height of the fixed element to min / max 80% 
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```